# Resolving a Javascript promise in iOS using JavascriptCore

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

I currently have some external `Javascript` code (**that is executed asynchronously**) that an iOS app interfaces with and can evaluate portions of conditionally. Right now, when the `Javascript` functions return, they return a "promise" to the iOS app that needs to be resolved. Is there any way to resolve a promise in iOS via `JavascriptCore`; or am I fighting a losing battle here and should I instead be resolving "all" promises in `Javascript` prior to returning values back to iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Give a look to this library:
https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge
at least as an example.

It doesn't manage js Promise as a JS result in native code, which I think is not possible, but it implements a way to manage async JS calls from native code.

If I'm not wrong, the main logic to manage async JS calls is:

1. When native code needs to call async JS method, it stores native callback into a callbacks registry and assign it an identifier.
2. Then it calls JS method passing the callback identifier.
3. When the async JS method ends (using the Promise or whatever) it calls native code using the same callback identifier.
4. This allows the native code to call the callback stored in the registry.

The library is well structured allowing handler registration etc ..., but I think the raw logic for Native-->JS calls is basically that.